# how to include php file wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress

I'm just guessing it's possible so I tested and don't work for me. 
My Scenario here is :

```
function load_javascripts(){  
    wp_register_script( 'user-script', plugins_url( '/js/youtube-script.php', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'user-script' );  
}
add_action('init','load_javascripts');
```

I am including a PHP file that has a majority of javascript in it ([the include file](http://pastebin.com/9C4Vu94n))

Do you guys have any suggestion please ?

Comment: What exactly is the problem/question?

Comment: I'm not sure if I did it right. To have a php included on my plugin with javascripts in it

Comment: It should be no problem. As long as you have the extension .php for your file, the server will parse it as a php file and it will be send to the client as a javascript file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to inject PHP variables in your javascript files.

PHP Example

```
 <?php
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
$array_to_js = array( 'some_string' =>'hello world' );
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $array_to_js );
?>
```

Javascript:

```
 <script>
alert(object_name.some_string); // alerts 'hello world'
</script>
```

Comment: hmmmn, I don't seem to understand it.

I am trying to include a javascript file which is also using PHP variables to my wordpress plugin. not just an javascript object

Comment: You are sending your PHP variable using `wp_localize_script` and then retrieving it as an object. Read [this](http://pippinsplugins.com/use-wp_localize_script-it-is-awesome/) and [that](http://ottopress.com/2010/passing-parameters-from-php-to-javascripts-in-plugins/) to get a better idea.

Comment: thanks @rrikesh, I have done it and it works.. can you suggest me for a more passing values here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633450/passing-a-javascript-array-to-php-variable-on-the-same-php-file

Comment: You should consider accepting my answer if it helped you (click on the green `tick` sign next to my answer. I answered your other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14644486/1370034

Comment: hi, yeah I appreciate your answer and helped me. where's the tick you're saying? I can't vote up on your answer yet.